# Range slider to change function argument in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to make a slider range that changes the value of an argument of a function

I have a slider like this:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0.5" max="2.5" value="1.2" step="0.1" class="slider" id="limit">
</div>
```

It supposed to change the value "1.2" argument:

```
def summarize (sentences, sentences_value, limit): ...

summary = summarize(sentences, sentences_value, 1.2 * average_score)
```

What can I do? Do i have to place the function in a views?

Thank you

Comment: if you have it in `<form>` then `<button>` `Submit` should send it to server and then you can get it and use in `sumarize` - and send it but with on new page. If you want to do it without reloading page then you will need to use JavaScript and AJAX to send it to servers and get result from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, let me give you two to kick it off:

**1.) Async handler**

You can use `jQuery Ajax` to transmit the new sliders value via an async `Ajax request` to your server, use the value to run your logic and return whatever is needed via the `Ajax success function` to manipulate the frontend again.

**2.) Sync handler**

You can submit any new slider value by hitting a button or something to request the server and have the page updated totally with the new returned data. Therefor you would just need to implement the submit logic to trigger the Django view.

At the backend, you will always have to trigger a view which basically represents a function in Django. Within that view you return whatever is needed to the frontend again.

Also note that in the case of an async handler the trigger function shouldn't be `on slide` since this will result in a huge computation loop usually and will slow down performance. Either you use `on drop` or `submit`.

Javascript wise I highly suggest to look into [noUi Slider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/)